# Ordering rows when using IN on Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I'm trying to get some SQL result from a list of ids. I have my ids ordered just as I need them, but when I pull the result from the query, the ids are not ordered as I need them.

[image]

I need the `idParada` ordered just as I sent them on the `IN`. I heard there is a order by FIELD on mysql but it doesn't not work for SQL Server.

Comment: The order of the elements on the `IN` are completely irrelevant to the order of your resultset. You should have a table with the order you want on another column

Comment: The IN clause order doesn't mean anything to the result set order. If you need that specific order it can be done in the ORDER BY clause. (With lots of typing.)

Comment: It'd be interesting to know why this specific order is important!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have SQL Server 2012+, use `choose()`:

```
select *
from Paradas
where iparada in (21, 22, . . . )
order by choose(iparada, 21, 22, . . .);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a case to get your specific order:

```
select * from Paradas
where iparada in (21,22 ...)
order by case iparada when 21 then 1
                      when 22 then 2
                      ...
                   end
```